# Cannot convert float to float* error, but I saved the variable as an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting the error even though (I think) I'm storing the magnitude array as a float* variable.  Why does it say that it is a non-array float variable?

The specific error says "cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘float stdev(int, float*, float&)’
 sta=stdev(length,magnitude[length],avg);"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;


float stdev(int,float*,float&);


int main(void) {

int length=3;
float* magnitude=new float[length];
magnitude[0]=1;
magnitude[1]=2;
magnitude[2]=3;

float sta,avg;
sta=stdev(length,magnitude[length],avg);

cout << "Standard Deviation is" << sta << endl;
return 0;
}




float stdev(int N,float* a,float avg) {

float stdv;
float sum=0;
for (int k=0;k<N;k++) {
    sum=sum+a[k];

}    
   avg=sum/N;

float s = 0;   

  for (int k=0;k<N;k++) 
  s=s+(a[k]-avg)*(a[k]-avg);   

 stdv=sqrt(s/N); 

return stdv;

}
```

Comment: Instead of `magnitude[length]`, use just `magnitude` in the call to `stdev`. `magnitude[length]` evaluates to a `float` while `magnitude` is a `float*`, which is what you need.

Comment: magnitude[length] will have type float not float*. Call the function with magnitude as the parameter instead of magnitude[length]. Also, magnitude[length] is actually outside the bounds of the array you created because arrays in c/c++ start at index 0 and range to length -1.

Comment: That fixed the one error but brought up another one:  undefined reference to `stdev(int, float*, float&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status,   I don't know what this could be referring to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call stdev as stdev(length, magnitude, avg).

magnitude[length] will have type float not float*. Call the function with magnitude as the parameter instead of magnitude[length]. Also, magnitude[length] is actually outside the bounds of the array you've created because arrays in c/c++ start at index 0 and range to length -1.

Simply pass the name of the array as the parameter.

Comment: "See my comment on your answer." - That's not how it works.

Comment: I gave an answer and my comment adds to it. I could copy and paste my comment if that would make you happy.

Comment: It is not what "makes me happy", but you should follow site rules instead of giving snotty comments. Comments (to the question) are not to complete your answer. But if you prefer downvotes without a comment saying why, just tell me, next time I will just DV and spare me a comment.

Comment: javey, that fixed the one error but brought up another one: undefined reference to `stdev(int, float*, float&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status, I don't know what this could be referring to

Comment: @Olaf sorry if it came off as snotty, but I had thought your first comment was equally. Now I will update my answer to not include a reference to my comment and instead give more detail within the answer its self.

Comment: @Christian try giving your function prototype for stdev(), at the top of your file, parameter names. I.e. float stdev(int N, float * a, float avg). Also, I would recommend giving your parameters more descriptive names, especially if you don't have comments to explain their meanings.